# Debugging and Running a Mono-Droid application

Tags: android, visual-studio-2010, android-emulator, xamarin.android

I have been quite interested in developing an application for my Android device. I downloaded the all the required tools for VS2010 following this guide - http://mono-android.net/Installation/Visual_Studio and everything went pretty smoothly.

Now, the first time I ran the default application and it copied everything to the emulator, it ran perfectly. If I make a simple change to the application and **hit F5** to redeploy - it starts the app, **but** it seems to have the old version on there still and doesn't show my changes. I've cleaned the solution and rebuilt the application, so I don't think its that. I've also completely changed the code (just in case it was something I was doing wrong), but that didn't work either. Oh and the build also succeeds!

Now the Emulator seems a bit flaky and slow...but is it something that I am doing? Is there somewhere I need to clear before hitting F5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it is doing the deploy, does it say "Uninstalling the previous version"?

Another thing to try is to manually remove the app from the emulator (Settings -> Applications -> Manage Applications ->  -> Uninstall.  Then deploy again and see if the new version is copying.  This should narrow down if it's a deployment issue or a build issue.

Comment: Yeah, I've been having a lot of problems with getting the emulator to work. It takes ages to start up and its been hanging on the "installing mono framework" part of the deploy. It doesnt even get to the "Uninstalling the previous version" part. I might just reinstall the whole thing again.....Thanks for the advice tho!